# How to determine from which thread a queue item comes from in queue.get() -- python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I have 2 child threads that put items (arrays) in a queue(using `queue.put()`. How can i tell from which thread a single item is returned to the main thread(using `queue.get()`).

I need to know because the arrays have to be saved on file based on their source.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply: add the information in what you put in the queue, ie instead of

```
queue.put(myarray)
```

use

```
queue.put({"source": whatever_identifies_your_source, "data": myarray})
```

Comment: in the "source" field should i put an identifier? and what should i write in the `q.get()` in the main thread to sort the arrays by that identifier?

Comment: How could I know what you should use as an identifier ??? It's your project, if _you_ don't have the answer to this question then nobody does.

Comment: i'm sorry. what i mean is that in the main thread i want to save this arrays as string in different files depending from which thread they come from.

so when i get the items from the queue how exactly i separate them based on said identifier

Comment: i get it. but somehow `q.get({"source" : id, "data": myarray}` in the main thread is doing nothing. Doesn't throw errors but neither works if i `print(myarray)` right after

Comment: ok i figured it out, i thought for a second that the args you put in queue.put where a specific method from the queue module. i wasn't thinking

Comment: I only pass one single arg to `queue.put()`. The difference is that instead of just passing the array directly, I wrap it in a dict (under the "data" key) which also contains the source id under the "source" key.

Comment: yeah thanks for your answer, it works. I was not thinking of a dictionary at all for some reason and thought that `queue.put({"source": whatever_identifies_your_source, "data": myarray})` was another way of passing args to the q.put() function.

Comment: Arf ! Time for a cup of coffee I guess ;-)